# How do I get awk to NOT use space as a delimeter?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, space

I've got a CSV that I'm trying to process, but some of my fields contain commas, line breaks and spaces and now that I think about it, there's probably some apostrophes in there too.

For the commas and line breaks, I've converted them to other strings at the output phase and convert them back at the end (yes it's messy but I only need to run this once) I realise that I may have to do this with the spaces too but I've broken the problem down to it's basic parts to see if I can work around it

Here's an input.csv

```
"john","beatles.com","arse","fool@wonka.com","1","1","on holiday"
"paul","beatles.com","bung","","0","1","also on holiday"
```

(I've tried with and without quotes)

here's the script

```
INPUT="input.csv"

for i in `cat ${INPUT}`

do
#USERNAME=`echo $i | awk -v  FS=',' '{print $1}'`
USERNAME=`echo $i | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[|,:]"} ; {print $1}'`
echo "username: $USERNAME"

done
```

So that should just input john and paul but instead I get

```
username: "john"
username: holiday"
username: "paul"
username: on
username: holiday"
```

because it sees the spaces and interprets them as new rows.

Can I get it to stop that?

Comment: perhaps just write a four-line Python script?  the builtin `csv` module can parse this no problem.

Comment: You have a problem in your `for i in $(cat ...)`: `i` will successively take the values `"john","beatles.com","arse","fool@wonka.com","1","1","on`, `holiday"
`, `"paul","beatles.com","bung","","0","1","also`, `on`, `holiday"`. That's not an `awk` problem.

Comment: Do never, never use `for i in $(cat ...)`. Who showed you this? find him and let him know that not only he's doing things wrong, but also he's spreading bad practices and wasted your time. You should really be mad at him.

Comment: Now, just to make sure you get things right: **Do not parse csv files with `awk`, `sed`, `bash`, etc.** Use a proper csv parser. There are lots of them that are very good in Python, Perl, etc. (this is just an advice so that you don't waste your time with methods that are broken from the start).

Comment: Get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins (quick!) and then only use shell to call tools, as it's intended.

Answer (score 3):

It's not `awk`, but the shell (the default value of `IFS`) that's causing word splitting.

You could fix that by saying:

```
while read -r i; do
  USERNAME=$(echo "$i" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[|,:]"} ; {print $1}');
  echo "username: $USERNAME";
done < $INPUT
```

---

In order to verify how the shell is reading the input, add

```
echo "This is a line: ${i}"
```

in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any regex field separator in awk, eg using optional comma followed by double quote:

```
awk -F ',?"' '{print $2, $4, $6, $8, $10, $12, "<" $14 ">"}' f1
john beatles.com arse fool@wonka.com 1 1 <on holiday>
paul beatles.com bung  0 1 <also on holiday>
```

Enclose last field `$14` n `< and >` to showcase how it gets in a single awk variable.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to note, you don't need to use `cat` or a `for` loop. Unless I am missing the bigger picture...

What happens when you call awk on the file?

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' input.csv
```

I get the following:

```
$ awk -F"," '{print $1}' input.csv
"john"
"paul"
$
```

Answer (score 0):

An awk-free solution:

```
cut -d, -f1 input.csv | while read -r USERNAME ; do echo "username: ${USERNAME}" ; done
```

The above assumes you want to keep the quotes.  If not...

```
cut -d, -f1 input.csv | sed 's,^",,;s,"$,,' | while read -r USERNAME ; do echo "username: ${USERNAME}" ; done
```

Both of the above also assume there are no commas in your field contents.  If that's not true, use a "proper" CSV parser in your favorite scripting language.  Example...

```
ruby -rcsv -ne 'puts CSV.parse_line($_)[0]' input.csv | while read -r USERNAME ; do echo "username: ${USERNAME}" ; done
```